# LINQ To SQL Class diagram in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, class, diagram

Is there a way to copy the class diagram generated by the LINQ To SQL ORM in VS2008 without using print screen (yes, I know it's pathetic)?

For example, when I create database projects in Visual Studio I can copy the database diagrams and save them later in Paint.NET in any image format. Any idea or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print as PDF works for me using Acrobat.

Comment: Why didn't I think of doing that? Haha I even have Cute PDF installed. Anyways, it's very strange that VS doesn't have something as straightforward as that copying a generated class diagram. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.

[Cropper](http://www.codeplex.com/cropper) is a great alternative for PrintScreen

Comment: Nice tool, will come in very handy. +1

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this through Visual Studio.  However a quick web search revealed the existence of a produce called [Entity Developer Express](http://www.bestsoftware4download.com/software/t-free-entity-developer-express-download-kmhriozh.html) that appears to provide this facility.  It's free too.

Comment: Nice tool, will definitely check it out. Thanks +1